# Parse log entries using Apache Log4j 2

Tags: apache, logging, log4j2

I have searched StackOverflow and the net for examples of how to use Apache Log4j 2 to parse existing log files. I have read that Apache has a sub-project "Chainsaw" that is a viewer for log-files and that it should also have an API that it would be possible to use to parse log entries yourself. However, I haven't been able to find any good readings on this, and I can't find Chainsaw in Apache Log4j 2.

What I would is something like the following (pseudo code/API):

```
String existingLogEntry = "2014-01-20 14:48:00,000 [thread-0] DEBUG (MyClass.java) - Some message";
String logPattern = "<substitute this with Log4j pattern that matches the above log entry>";

LogEntry entry = Parser.parse(logPattern, existingLogEntry);
System.out.println("Date: " + entry.getDate());
System.out.println("Time: " + entry.getTime());
System.out.println("Thread: " + entry.getThread());
System.out.println("Log level: " + entry.getLogLevel());
System.out.println("Class: " + entry.getClassName());
System.out.println("Message: " + entry.getMessage());
```

So I need to know:

1. Which dependencies to include in my Maven pom.xml file?
2. How to construct a simple example that can take a Log4j pattern and an existing log entry based on this pattern and then use the API to extract relevant information?

It should also be possible to extract custom values/MDC/Markes.